# Take Screenshot and Share to Social media's Phonegap Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to take screenshot of application screen(result page) and then want to share on social media. I try to use https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot but it give me a error https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbpvZ.png . I am using phonegap 3.4.0.

Answer (score 7):

Install the following plugins in your application

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
```

And

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot.git
```

Plugins for PhoneGap can be similarly installed by replacing 'cordova' with 'phonegap local'

After installing the plugins, prepare your project by executing

```
$ cordova prepare
```

Add the following code in your script:

```
<script>
    function sharePhoto() {
     var imageLink;
            console.log('Calling from CapturePhoto');
            navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
            if(error){
            console.error(error);
            }else{
            console.log('ok',res.filePath); //should be path/to/myScreenshot.jpg
            //For android
            imageLink = res.filePath;
           window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null,'file://'+imageLink, null);

           //For iOS
           //window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null,   null,imageLink, null)
     }
     },'jpg',50,'myScreenShot');
    }
</script>
```

Call the above function on button click as follows:

```
<button onclick="sharePhoto();">Share Screenshot</button>
```

If you are not able to see the log in console install the following plugin and prepare your project again.

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git
```